# Given the Hessian of a scalar function of two variables, find the function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Suppose we are given the Hessian of a scalar function of two variables, 
$\nabla^2_{f(x,y)}$, do there exist explicit formulas for finding $f(x,y)$?

Attempt: Brute-Force method is to do double integrals of the mixed partial derivatives and add them. The solution however would be correct upto an additive constant (which could be a function of either $x$ or $y$. Example, 
$$f(x,y) := x^2 + 4xy + y^2 + x$$ then the Hessian is given by $$\nabla^2_f := \left[\begin{array}{cc} 2 & 4 \\ 4 & 2\end{array}\right]$$ If one were to double integrate the mixed partial derivatives, we would get $x^2, 4xy, 4xy, y^2$. And one can claim that the function is $x^2 + 4xy + y^2 + c$, where $c = g(x)$ or $c = g(y)$.

Any other suggestions? Are there any explicit formulas for the Hessian? Like double integral of the Hessian etc.?

Comment: Integration is the right approach (and the only one), but note that for a second derivative, it's not correct up to a *constant*, but rather up to a *linear term*. In other words, any term of the form $ax+by+c$, where $a,b,c$ re constants, is lost when taking the second derivative.